# JavaScript - Calling a variable object inside of a variable object

Tags: javascript

I'm new to StackOverflow and coding. I want to know if it is possible to call a variable object within a variable object in JavaScript.

Maybe something like this:

```
var info {
    name: function() {
              document.write("Jordan");
              last: function() { 
                        document.write("Baron");
                    }
          }
```

So when you call info.name(), it does document.write("Jordan), and when you do info.name().last(), it does document.write("Baron")

If it's a stupid question, be brutal. I want to learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a stupid question, a very good one in my opinion. Try this:

```
var info = {
    name: function() {
        document.write("Jordan");
        return {
            last: function() {
                document.write("Baron");
            }
        };
    }
}

info.name();
info.name().last();
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8777x65q/)

You have to return an object which contains a function to have a possibility to call it. The only con of code above is that `document.write("Jordan");` is called in both cases - when `info.name();` and `info.name().last();` are invoked. If it's not an expected behavior, try this:

```
var info = {
    name: function() {
        return { 
            first: function(){
                document.write("Jordan");
            },
            last: function() {
                document.write("Baron");
            }
        };
    }
}

info.name().first();
info.name().last();
```

Comment: …or use `var x = info.name();` and  `x.last()` to call them separately.